# get values from a data frame using a series

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['x','y','w','x','y','w','x','y','w','x','y','w'],'b':['m','m','m','f','f','f','m','m','m','f','f','f'],'c':range(1,13)})  
rows = df.loc[:,['a','b']].drop_duplicates()
```

Let's say I'd like to get the values in `c` for a specific row, eg `rows.iloc[0]`.
I know I can do

```
>> df.loc[(df.a=='x')&(df.b=='m'),'c']

   [1, 7]
```

but in my actual data frame I have many columns and I want to do this over the rows of `rows`, which is why I'm looking for a more dynamic way of doing this.

Comment: Are you looking for something like: `df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].agg(list)`?

Comment: you can use a list comprehension and multi condition your if statement.   you can use an lambda in an dataframe apply.   How many conditions exist?  will the conditions need to be dynamically created

Comment: sounds interesting. Can you develop what you means `over the rows of rows`, pls.

Comment: @ALollz thanks, I completely forgot about groupby, even though I use it all the time...

Comment: @antoine I mean to get the values in `c` that correspond to `rows.iloc[0]`, then `rows.iloc[1]`, and so on

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about performance, a convenient solution would be:

`result = df.set_index(['a', 'b']).loc[(<index_value_1>, <index_value_2>)]`

if you need the values of c.